# Unable to Cherry Pick (FETCH), but able to Pull & Push in Gerrit Git

Tags: git, gerrit

As I said in the title, I am able to push to the gerrit, pull from the gerrit, but I am not able to cherry pick. When I asked the admin, he said I have all the rights to cherry pick, but I get the error as:

#### Error Message

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

#### When I try to Pull and Rebase

```
praveen@praveen-vbox:~/work/myapp$ git pull --rebase
remote: Counting objects: 8888, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (615/615)
remote: Total 615 (delta 416), reused 536 (delta 416)
Receiving objects: 100% (615/615), 267.47 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (416/416), completed with 163 local objects.
From gerrit:myapp
   b7b8734..f5a782b  master     -> origin/master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Fast-forwarded master to f5a782b97079491e25638c9a752794e3af0a7543.
```

#### When I try to check the status

```
praveen@praveen-vbox:~/work/myapp$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

#### When I try to Commit

```
praveen@praveen-vbox:~/work/myapp$ git commit
[master 4c41a43] Minor fixes
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

#### When I try to Push

```
praveen@praveen-vbox:~/work/myapp$ git push gerrit:myapp HEAD:refs/for/master
Counting objects: 20, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 896 bytes, done.
Total 10 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (9/9)
remote: Processing changes: updated: 1, done
To gerrit:myapp
 * [new branch]      HEAD -> refs/for/master
```

#### When I try to Cherry Pick

```
praveen@praveen-vbox:~/work/myapp$ git fetch ssh://praveen@my.appdomain.com:29418/myapp refs/changes/24/5324/2 && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

#### Summary

My application runs on **Ubuntu 12.04** on a **VirtualBox** instance. All my peers are able to `cherry-pick`, and I find the issue is only with my machine, and that too with `cherry-pick` by **`FETCH`**. What might be the issue? What do you guys suggest? What information other than this, do you need?

---

#### Update #1

#### Git Config

```
praveen@praveen-vbox:~/work/myapp$ git config --list
alias.s=status
alias.c=commit
alias.ca=commit --amend
alias.co=checkout
alias.dc=diff --color
alias.l=log --oneline
alias.pr=pull --rebase
alias.aa=add .
user.email=[removed] /* Removed before posting to SO. Email matches. */
core.editor=vim
color.ui=always
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
remote.origin.url=gerrit:myapp.git
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

#### For [Titas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/750495/titas)'s query, the result is:

```
praveen@praveen-vbox:~/work/myapp$ git fetch gerrit refs/changes/96/5396/3
fatal: 'gerrit' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

#### Also, when I do normally, this is the result:

```
praveen@praveen-vbox:~/work/myapp$ git fetch ssh://praveen@my.appdomain.com:29418/myapp refs/changes/96/5396/3 && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

---

#### Update #2: SSH Config

As requested by [RasmusØstergaardKjærVoss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1847483/rasmus-ostergaard-kjaer-voss), I have included below the SSH Config file. Let me know if there's something to be changed.

```
praveen@praveen-vbox:~/work/myapp$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host gerrit
HostName my.appdomain.com
Port 29418
User praveen
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/praveen_private
```

Comment: the fetch is failing, not the cherry-pick (cherry-pick is a local operation)

Comment: Okay, so this is the issue. How do I fix it? Will update the question @NikoSams.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - how does your .gitconfig file look like? Niko is right, the fetch must be failing, not the cherry-pick.

What you should investigate, is what remote is pull using and try to use exactly the same for fetch.

What happens if you do:
git fetch gerrit refs/changes/24/5324/2

Comment: @Titas Thanks. Am at home. Will to it exactly in 15 hours and let you know the results. `:)`

Comment: @Titas I have updated with what you have asked. Please let me know what can I do. `:)`

Comment: What did you configure in ~/.ssh/config seems like there is a different in domains or something compared to what you have in the ~/.ssh/config
Perhaps that is where the error is ?

Comment: @RasmusØstergaardKjærVoss Let me check that and update the same in few hours. :)

Comment: @RasmusØstergaardKjærVoss I have updated with the config file too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~/.ssh/`, to my understanding `git fetch ssh://praveen@my.appdomain.com:29418/` will use the `id_rsa` key and not the `~/.ssh/praveen_private`.

Backup your `~/.ssh` folder Then try and create a copy of `~/.ssh/praveen_private` named `~/.ssh/id_rsa` If it is an `rsa` key otherwise copy it to `~/.ssh/id_dsa`

Cheers

Comment: Will try this and let you know. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your settings in git or gerrit, or in the overall settings for your gerrit deployment.  You can run a `git pull`, which basically runs `git fetch && git merge` under the covers.  But you can't run the `git fetch` command you copy-paste from gerrit.  Look at the output of `git remote -v` and compare it to the `git fetch` portion of the cherry-pick command you are trying to run.  Are you hitting the exact same server URL & port?  As the same user?

Lastly, as a connection test to Gerrit, try running something like `ssh username@gerrit_host -p 29418 gerrit ls-projects`.  This should return a list of projects on the Gerrit server, and is a good way to work out any setting issues.

Answer (score 0):

This gave me the same error:

```
ssh firstname.lastname@my.appdomain.com
```

changing to:

```
ssh firstname.lastname@gerrit.appdomain.co
```

fixed the problem for me.